# Define shortcut key for shortcut in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut-file

I want to create PowerShell script that makes a shortcut but i couldn't find function to define **Shortcut key:** for created shortcut. I mean, when *Properties* of shortcut are opened there is an input field for *Shortcut key*, is there any function to define it in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found the solution:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/11/03/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-a-windows-powershell-shortcut-to-the-quick-launch-toolbar/

Function is `HotKey`. Something like this: `$shortcut.HotKey = "CTRL+1"`